# Getting Type not found error implementing source in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, import, implementation

I am trying to just compile and run the demos from this article:

[Flash talks to max msp via osc](http://blog.derhess.de/2011/08/16/flash-talks-to-max-msp-via-osc/comment-page-1/#comment-3193)

I am using Flash Develop and Flex SDK with an up to date version of air.

When I run the demo: "as3_MaxFlashHarmony" I get an error I don't know how to fix. The source for the entire project is here:

[the project](http://code.google.com/p/derhess/source/browse/trunk/AS3/de/derhess/projects/#projects%2Fair_MaxFlashHarmony)

But specifically the error I am getting says:

```
col: 30 Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: OSCMessage.
```

here is the as3 file that it is specifically referencing:

```
//IHarmonyApp.as
package 
{
    import org.tuio.osc.OSCMessage;

    public interface IHarmonyApp
    {
        function updateOSCData(msg:OSCMessage):void;
    }
}
```

It uses the libraries Tuio, MinimalComps, and MonsterDebugger. The thing I don't get is that how can it not find OSCMessage if OSCMessage is properly imported? the IDE is making fine references to it and I can open it's declaration. OSCMessage is a public class. I don't get it.

To give some extra info for potential answers, the IDE flashdevelop can find the library org.tuio.osc.OSCMessage just fine, it gives the error regardless of if org.tuio... is a source path or not, and the overall path does not contain any special characters. I don't know if that might matter, but I feel like this is me making a stupid mistake somewhere. I can provide my project zipped if need be.

Thanks!

Edit 9:48, 8/25/12
I do have the file path org/tuio/osc/OSCMessage.as in my project, and the file OSCMessage exists. FlashDevelop can find it just fine and I can navigate to declaration at that location. This is why I got stumped.
Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your AS3 folder apart of your **de** folder you would need to have **org** folder with relevant folders and classes.

For example to import org.tuio.osc.OSCMessage you would need a file:

../YourPackageRoot/org/tuio/osc/OSCMessage.as

The other way is including a SWC file (all folders and classes zipped into one swc file).
You can include the swc file in FlashDevelop by right clicking the swc file and selecting **Add To Library**

Comment: I have that file in my project space, and it is properly in the org/tuio/osc.. That is sort of what I tried to explain saying my IDE can find it. It is in my project space and exists. So in short I have: [project folder]/org/tuio/osc/OSCMessage.as already. UPDATE if you mean in my ProgramFiles/FlashDevelop/Libraries/AS3 folder, then I tried that and it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: can you add the org folder in your project in the link you provided? I could tell you more then

Comment: The link is the source I am implementing from, it is someone else's code, I will post an edit with my project zipped in a second, Thank you for your help.

Comment: I made a google code project for my working copy where I am getting the error that includes the flash develop project. Maybe this will help? http://code.google.com/p/flash-max-msp-implementation-for-help/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2F%20flash-max-msp-implementation-for-help

Comment: move the whole org folder into your src folder, and see if it works

Comment: Yep! Thank you. I knew it was something simple that I just wasn't getting. It's a localpath thing isn't it? I always mess those up. Thanks again, that worked